# to change the latitude and longitude dynamically of location in map iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

how can i dynamically get the latitude and longitude so that when the user keeps on walking from his current position his direction on the map should also keep on changing.How is this possible

Comment: Take a look at this example: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/getting-your-location-in-an-iphone-application it shows how to constantly update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could make use of MKMapview's property `showsUserLocation`

Taken from [MKMapView Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html)

showsUserLocation

A Boolean value indicating whether the map may display the user location.
@property(nonatomic) BOOL showsUserLocation
Discussion

This property does not indicate whether the user’s position is actually visible on the map, only whether the map view is allowed to display it. To determine whether the user’s position is visible, use the userLocationVisible property. The default value of this property is NO.

Setting this property to YES causes the map view to use the Core Location framework to find the current location. As long as this property is YES, the map view continues to track the user’s location and update it periodically.

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to 7KV7's answer (i can't respond to answers directly yet), if you need to know when it has updated, add the *mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:* method to your delegate:
[method's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html%22didUpdateUserLocation%20documentation%22)